# I am planning to build a Windows 7 gadget for Stack Exchange.

Tags: discussion, windows

Hello,

I am planning to start development of a windows 7 gadget for stack exchange.Specifically stack overflow.

I would like some guidance, on where to get good designs, HCI patterns, etc for the same.

Also, a vote, which tells me , how good/bad the idea would be a nice way to judge, if the work I put in would be worth it.

Thanks

PS:I was trying to put a windows-7-gadgets tag, but it didnt workIf someone could remove that restriction on me, I would be glad.

Comment: I don't know how anyone could vote for "Windows 7 gadget" without having any idea what it would do.

Comment: On meta, several people are wishing for a "global inbox" and a "reputation dropdown" gadget.

Comment: I personally think  stack-exchange/overflow/app gadget would be great. They have some out, none with the desired functionality though.